# display javascript message in div element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the below code to get the selected checkbox closest value. and i am successfully getting the values in alert box. But I want to display it in div element with some CSS to it. so that I can display it as Modal. could you please help?

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    //Assign Click event to Button.
    $("#match").click(function () {
        var message = "FUND_ID FUND_Name ISIN\n";

        //Loop through all checked CheckBoxes in GridView.
        $("#my_fo_id input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr")[0];
            message += row.cells[1].innerHTML;
            message += "   " + row.cells[2].innerHTML;
            message += "   " + row.cells[3].innerHTML;
            message += "\n";

        });

        //Display selected Row data in Alert Box.
       alert(message);

    });
});
```

Comment: check out jQuery documentation for `.html()` method
[https://api.jquery.com/html/](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

basically, you can achive this by 
`$('#div').html(message);`

Comment: yeah I tried this in js "$("#error").html(message);" and html as <div class="modal-body">
                        <p id="error"></p>
                      </div>

Comment: @Prashant could you provide your HTML, CCS and JavaScript in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @BrOsCoRe , unfortunately I am not allowed to share the complete code. however the current script I posted is working fine. I am getting results as expected but in a alert box. so I want it in <div> </div>

Answer (score 2):

Just use this to add the message to a div-

```
$('#customModal').html(message);
```

and add this in HTML-

```
<div id="customModal"></div>
```

Your message will get added to div with id="customModal". Now you can play with it using CSS. You have to remove `alert(message);` so that it will not popup the alert window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BrOsCoRe/L4mf7xgq/11/)

```
$(".open").on("click", function(){
    var message = "test";
  $("h2").after("<p>" + message + "</p>");
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
this is another way to display message
function comment() {
    var question = document.getElementById("question").value
    var question2 = document.getElementById("question2").value
        if(question != question2) {
            alert('You entered two different comment, please make sure both password fields match.');
        }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

create a hidden modal in html,set the value of a text field and make the modal visible?

Comment: Post it as a comment, not a solution